# React setState not updating checkbox checked state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm following a React beginners tutorial making a todo app as an example.

in the App.js, there is a handleChange method that will update the state whether the checkbox is checked or not, and passes it into the TodoItem component

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            todos: todosData
        }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    }

    handleChange(id) {
      console.log(id)
        this.setState(prevState => {
            const updatedTodos = prevState.todos.map(todo => {
                if (todo.id === id) {
                    todo.completed = !todo.completed
                }
                return todo
            })
            return {
                todos: updatedTodos
            }
        })
    }

    render() {
        const todoItems = this.state.todos.map(item => <TodoItem key={item.id} item={item} handleChange={this.handleChange}/>)
        return (
            <div className="todo-list">
                 {todoItems}
            </div>
        )    
    }
}
export default App
```

TodoItem.js

```
function TodoItem(props) {
    return (
        <div className="todo-item">
            <input 
                type="checkbox" 
                checked={props.item.completed} 
                onChange={() => props.handleChange(props.item.id)}
            />
            <p>{props.item.text}</p>
        </div>
    )
}
export default TodoItem
```

it successfully displays the list and the console log correctly displays the checkbox clicked, however, the checkbox does not change. Can anyone tell me the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are running into a state mutation problem which is causing some unexpected behavior. The reason for this is because inside your `if statement` within `map` you are not returning your modified array item and you are actually modifying your state array and your new array.

**How to fix: return your modified array item inside the if statement**

```
this.setState(prevState => {
    const updatedTodos = prevState.todos.map(todo => {
        if (todo.id === id) {
            return {
             ...todo,
             completed: !todo.completed
            }
        }
        return todo
    })
    return {
        todos: updatedTodos
    }
})
```

**Or use a one liner with conditional (ternary) operator:**

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  ...prevState,
  todos: prevState.todos.map(todo => todo.id === id ? { ...todo, ...{ completed: !todo.completed } } : todo)
}))
```

Look at this example I created in [playground](https://playcode.io/674821) to get a better understanding:

I defined two arrays, one array uses `map()` without the return and the other array is using `map()` with the return.

Our goal is to keep our two arrays exactly the same and using `map()` to create a new modified array. Look at the log results and notice how our initial array gets modified aswell. Our second todo item in this array should have a `completed` value of `true` but it gets changed to `false` after our `map()` which we would want to avoid. By returning our array item in the correct way we avoid this.

To get a better understanding of what state mutation is and how to avoid check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37755997/why-cant-i-directly-modify-a-components-state-really).

Comment: Copied your code from sandbox, everything works nice now. I'm still new with React, so I learned something new today, thanks a lot!